# Import Data from Views

Tags: sql-server, sql-insert

Is it possible to import data from views in another db. So our old database is rather large having several tables with different relationships, sometimes the tables can be 2 columns long. We have views that pull the data from these different tables. Is it possible  to insert the values from these views into another db?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
USE newdb
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tbl', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.tbl
GO

SELECT *
INTO dbo.tbl
FROM old_db.dbo.view1
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what your query does?

Comment: you store results from view into a new table... check syntax - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx

Comment: small check... that object already exists in db - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190328.aspx